# Sticky scroll container not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

For some reason, this works in all major browsers, but not IE (surprise, surprise).

```
$(function() {
var stickyDiv = $('#js-sticky-wrap'); // div to clone
var clonedCss = 'js-sticky-fix'; // css class with fixed positioning
stickyContainer(stickyDiv, clonedCss);

function stickyContainer(stickyDiv, clonedCss, clonedWidth) {
    if (clonedWidth === undefined) { // use original container width
        var clonedWidth = $(stickyDiv).width();
    }

    var menuTop = stickyDiv.offset().top; // Capture visible content height
    var menuClone = stickyDiv.clone(true).addClass(clonedCss); // Clone current div, apply fixed style
    var dropShadow = $('<div class="js-drop-shadow"></div>').hide();
    // Append dropshadow style
    stickyDiv.append(dropShadow);

    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        var scrollY = window.pageYOffset; // get total px from vertical scroll
        if (scrollY > menuTop) { // they scrolled > than the original offset
            if (menuClone.parent().length === 0) {
               stickyDiv.addClass(clonedCss).width(clonedWidth);
                menuClone.after(stickyDiv.parent());
                dropShadow.show();
            }
        } else {
            stickyDiv.removeClass(clonedCss);

            dropShadow.hide();
            menuClone.remove();
        }

    });
}
```

});

[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/someprimetime/KT7A2/11/)

Is there a method that just isn't supported with IE that I am using? Can't seem to pin it down, as I'm not getting any errors in developer tools.

Comment: @lostinplace Scroll down in the result box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**window.pageYOffset** is not supported by IE until version 9. Try using it like this:

```
var scrollY;
if (typeof(window.pageYOffset) == 'number') {
    scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
}
else {
    scrollY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
```

Comment: this also will not work, replace
    menuClone.after(stickyDiv.parent());
with
    menuClone.appendTo(stickyDiv.parent());

Comment: Well this certainly helped solve the problem of making it sticky, but of course, IE doesn't let me off easy and it introduced a different problem. Thanks nonetheless to you and @lostinplace.